# What happened to the Python interactive window?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am working on `MacOS v10.14.6` and using the Python interactive window of `VScode v1.38.1`.

I write code in a `.py` file and use `#%%` to create cells and `shift+enter` to run them in the interactive window.

Today the layout of the interactive window changed, but I didn't do any update and I did not change my settings.

It now shows icons on the top left (as on the screenshot below) instead of showing them on the top right, as it was the case before (as shown in the [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py)).

[image: my new layout of the python interactve window]

To me it looks like that doing shifts+enter now launchs a jupyter notebook similar to the one now supported by vscode, because the icons are similar. See the ones on this [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support) here.

The really annoying thing is that now my plots have a dark background, instead of a white one as it was the case before. 
I checked and the option `python.dataScience.ignoreVscodeTheme` is still set on `True`.

Do you have an idea what happened ?

Comment: Hey Louis, we did just publish a monthly release. However that release should have only had small changes to the Interactive Window workflow. The positioning of the buttons was one smaller expected change.

However I would not expect changes to shift-enter or to the ignoreVScodeTheme setting. I'll look into the ignoreflag myself now. Were you saying that shift-enter now launches the new notebook experience? That seems very strange, could you screen shot what you see after doing shift-enter and getting the new editor?

Comment: Hi Ian, what I obtain when I do shift+enter is the screenshot above in my question, this is the screenshot after having done shift+enter on the cell on the left side.
I downloaded vscode v1.39 and I unistalled/re-installed the python extension but the behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the info Louis. So you are still seeing the interactive window there, not the new notebook experience, we just made some tweaks to the icons and icon locations to match the interactive window up better with the new experience. However while much of that is expected we did break the ignoreVscodeTheme setting. We have an issue filed on that there and it's on our immediate list to fix. Sorry about that, and thanks for reporting.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7847